# Adding a listener to ComboBox#box.getSelectionModel()#selectedItemProperty() causes Exception since Java 8u72

Tags: java, exception, javafx, version, listener

The code below will generate a `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to MCVE$ComboBoxItem` exception if you choose an item from the `ComboBox` dropdown and then press another Control, in this case a `TextField`. The weirdest part is that this is caused by the following code:

```
box.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((o, oldVal, newVal) -> {
                // This is what causes  the issue. You don't even need to put anything here.
            });
```

Even though it practically doesn't do anything.

I have tested this on several platforms and with different java versions. And this bug seems to depend on the Java version. The program is tested in Java 8u60, 8u66 and 8u72, and the bug only occurred in Java 8u72.

MCVE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MCVE extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ComboBox<ComboBoxItem> box = new ComboBox<ComboBoxItem>();
        box.setEditable(true);

        ObservableList<ComboBoxItem> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new ComboBoxItem("Option 1"),
                new ComboBoxItem("Option 2"));
        box.setItems(items);

        box.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((o, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            // This is what causes  the issue. You don't even need to put anything here.
        });

        TextField textfield = new TextField();

        HBox root = new HBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(box, textfield);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        stage.show();
    }

    public class ComboBoxItem {
        private String text;

        public ComboBoxItem(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return text;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Full exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to MCVE$ComboBoxItem
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:74)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:102)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.lambda$new$152(ComboBox.java:249)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:105)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setValue(ComboBoxBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.setTextFromTextFieldIntoComboBoxValue(ComboBoxPopupControl.java:405)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.lambda$new$291(ComboBoxPopupControl.java:82)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.scene.Node$FocusedProperty.notifyListeners(Node.java:7718)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$13.invalidated(Scene.java:2077)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.setFocusOwner(Scene.java:3924)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.requestFocus(Scene.java:3971)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3910)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.requestFocus(Scene.java:2044)
    at javafx.scene.Node.requestFocus(Node.java:7879)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.mousePressed(TextFieldBehavior.java:248)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the issue isn't adding the listener, it's using a editable `ComboBox` without a appropriate [`StringConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/StringConverter.html).

This is certainly not a bug; it's even documented [in the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html):

> By default the converter simply returns the `String` input as the user typed it, which therefore assumes that the type of the editable `ComboBox` is `String`. If a different type is specified and the `ComboBox` is to be editable, it is necessary to specify a custom `StringConverter`.

I guess the listener just makes causes the exception, since the property can no longer be lazy evaluated or something like that...

You could use a `StringConverter` like this:

```
    box.setConverter(new StringConverter<ComboBoxItem>() {

        @Override
        public String toString(ComboBoxItem object) {
            return object == null ? null : object.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public ComboBoxItem fromString(String string) {
            return box.getItems().stream().filter(item -> item.text.equals(string)).findFirst().orElse(null);
        }
    });
```